# Listview and checkbox( how to put in database(sqlite))

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-cursoradapter

I'm new in android and developing an software ,which Show user contacts as listview with checkbox , How to Insert checkbox data into database, based on if it is checked or not?

In my database class, I have a function which use to add names and numbers to my database

```
createntry(String number,String name) // in my database class
```

I really tried to find the answer and figured out I should use getview function for this, but still couldn't find a solution.

My CursorAdapterClass

```
     public class ContactCursorAdapterCT extends CursorAdapter {
     private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
     private Context context1;
     DataBaseBON dd1= new DataBaseBON(context1);
         public ContactCursorAdapterCT(Context context, Cursor c) {

    super(context, c);
    this.context1 = context;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {
        itemChecked.add(i, false); // initializes all items value with false
    }

}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
      TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactlistTV1);      
          name.setText(cursor.getString
          (cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
          TextView phone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactlistTV2);                
           phone.setText(cursor.getString          
          (cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) { 
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lvct, parent, false);
            bindView(v, context, cursor);
    return v;

}

public View getView(final int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) { //getView 

    if (inView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context1
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lvct, null);
    }

    final CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox)inView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1); // my
    // CheckBox

    cBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                itemChecked.set(pos, true);

                      //My problem should be here??

            } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                itemChecked.set(pos, false);

            }
        }
    });
    cBox.setChecked(itemChecked.get(pos)); // this will Check or Uncheck the
    // CheckBox in ListView
    // according to their original
    // position and CheckBox never
    // loss his State when you
    // Scroll the List Items.
    return inView;
```

My activity class

```
   public class Contacts extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts);

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query
            (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
           ContactCursorAdapterCT adapter= new ContactCursorAdapterCT
           (Contacts.this, cursor);
       ListView contactLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewblcontactsDB);
           contactLV.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My database Class

```
  public long creatEntry(String inputnumber , String name) { // for add data   

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NUMBER, inputnumber);
    cv.put(N_NAME, name);
    Log.v(inputnumber, "adding to Database");
    return ourdatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
 }
```

Comment: where should I invoke createntry function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of simple DBhelper which allow to work with SQLite database. It has required methods to add new data and update saved data.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static DBHelper instance;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HangmanBase";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
public static interface ITEM extends BaseColumns {
        String TABLE_NAME = "itemTable";
        String NAME = "itemName";
        String CHECK = "itemCheck";
    }
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ";
    private static final String UNIQUE = "UNIQUE ON CONFLICT ABORT";
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ITEM = CREATE_TABLE + ITEM.TABLE_NAME + " (" + ITEM._ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + ITEM.NAME + " TEXT " + UNIQUE + ", " + ITEM.CHECK + " INTEGER);";
private DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBHelper(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ITEM);
    }
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE + ITEM.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
public long addWord(String name, boolean check) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ITEM.NAME, name);
        values.put(ITEM.CHECK, check);
        return getWritableDatabase().insert(ITEM.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
public Cursor getAllItemCursor() {
        return getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + ITEM.TABLE_NAME, null);
    }
public void changeItemCheck(String itemName, boolean isChecked) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ITEM.CHECK, isChecked);
        getWritableDatabase().update(ITEM.TABLE_NAME, values, ITEM.NAME + " =? ", new String[] { itemName });
    }
}
```

Simple activity with one ListView:

private ListView itemList;

private DBHelper dbHelper;

private CursorAdapter adapter;

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cursor_list);
        itemList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.item_list);
        dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(this);
        Cursor allItemCursor = dbHelper.getAllItemCursor();
        adapter = new ItemCursorAdapter(this, allItemCursor, true);
        itemList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

And example of SimpleCursorAdapter with custom OnCheckedChangeListener. Maybe its not the best way to save check changes to DB:

```
public class ItemCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int itemNameIndex;
    private int itemCheckIndex;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
public ItemCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, cursor, autoRequery);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        itemNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ITEM.NAME);
        itemCheckIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ITEM.CHECK);
        dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(context);
    }
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String name = cursor.getString(itemNameIndex);
        boolean checked = cursor.getInt(itemCheckIndex) > 0;
        TextView nameTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        CheckBox checkChk = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.item_check);
        checkChk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new onItemCheckChangeListener(name));
        nameTxt.setText(name);
        checkChk.setChecked(checked);
    }
@Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
        return view;
    }
private class onItemCheckChangeListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
private String itemName;
public onItemCheckChangeListener(String itemName) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }
@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            dbHelper.changeItemCheck(itemName, isChecked);
        }
}
}
```